# Resources for self-study of general topology

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, online-resources

Could you point me to good resources for self-study of general topology. I want to learn the basics and how to prove theorems about structures like polyhedra by myself.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure whether general topology studies polyhedra - that's generally approached by algebraic topology. General topology is often what is called "point-set topology."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can I safely study algebraic topology without studying general topology?

Comment: You need some basic point-set topology before you can get to algebraic topology, yes. I don't mean to imply that you won't need any of it, only that a lot of general topology is not needed, and general topology is not sufficient to study polyhedra.

Comment: "A first course in topology" by J. McCleary is a concise introduction to topology, and towards the end, it covers some theory about simplicial complexes (and polyhedra).

Comment: I found this resource: http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~olegviro/topoman/part1.pdf. Can you please take a quick look and tell me if that's good?

Comment: Topology without tears. Free/ Online/ fine for self study but may be not "how to prove theorems about structures like polyhedra by myself".

Comment: What do you mean by "topology without tears"?

Comment: Engelking's General Topology

Comment: I like the study of polyhedral.

Comment: It supposedly won’t drive you crazy learning topology,but there still is a lot of knashingb of teeth .@mrk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A great resource for self-study in Topology is James Munkres' [*Topology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131816292). You can "preview" the text and it contents at the link given. It's divided into two sections, the second being algebraic topology.

You'll also get an overview of [*Topology* (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), its branches and the topics related to those branches/subfields, to better hone in on your area of interest. There are a number of references cited, some with links, along with helpful resources that may aid in your self-study.

A good follow-up to Munkres, and more in the direction of your interests, I presume, is then (of course) *Algebraic Topology* by [Allen Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/) (freely and legally available online, courtesy of the author! The link takes you to Hatcher's home page, where you can access his text, as well as supplementary resources, e.g. notes in point-set-topology.) You might want to peruse Hatcher's text to get a better idea what preliminary material you should cover in Munkres; that might cut down on the amount of Munkres you'd want to cover.

Another sound intro to Topology is [*A First Course in Topology*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821838849) by J. McCleary (again, you can preview the text at the given link).

Comment: This book is available in my university's library: http://www.amazon.com/Three-Dimensional-Geometry-Topology-Vol-1/dp/0691083045. Is it worth reading?

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? What's wrong Amy!? I hope this + gets you better, although it is very small.

Comment: It only addressed part of the problem...anyway, thanks for you kind words! I'm having a slow-ish day today!

Comment: In fact, if you google "at.pdf" Hatcher's book shows up

Answer (score 6):

I would have to disagree slightly about the Munkres recommendation; It is a nice book, and the second edition was what was used when I studied topology at university. However, it may be a bit hard to use for self-study, since it is concerned very much with going though results and definitions, and does not go much into the motivations of those definitions, or their applications. A good lecturer can fill those in, but unfortunately I did not have one of those, so the book was not very useful to me. The same might be true when it's used for self-study.

I can recommend Ronald Brown's "Topology and Groupoids", however, which in my opinion manages to combine the "abstract" nature of topology with a concrete understanding very well. It is a bit idiosyncratic in that it is based more on category theory than set theory, but if what I've understood about the contemporary development of topology is right, that is the direction that the field is moving in anyway.

I have also heard good things about Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" (from people whose judgment I trust in these matters, that is) but I haven't studied it properly yet myself.

Comment: Bredon's book is at a different level than Munkres, probably not what OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

Another really good resource for topology is "Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis" by George Simmons. I used it alot in graduate school.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at [topology without tears](https://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) I am learning Topology right now using this book and found it quite helpful. It is free and there is an accompanying video series on his [website](https://www.topologywithouttears.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Fred H . Croom,
**Principles of Topology**

See: [Croom’s:Principles of Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486801543)

Here are partial list of the chapters:

1. Introduction
2. Line and the Plane
3. Metric Spaces
4. Topological Spaces
5. Connectednes
6. Compactness

Looking at the book,the layout is beautiful and the proofs
are clearly written showing you how to do the exercises.

Also another professor on another site suggested it over
Conover’s A First Course on Topology which I currently use
because Conover’s thesis was not shown in American Geneology of Mathematicians

Another excellent book you can get by hard back is

Bert Mendelson,**Introduction to Topology**

See:
[Mendleson’s Introduction to Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486663523)

It is heavy on metric spaces.

Here is a list of the chapters:

1.Theory of Sets

2.Metric Spaces

3.Topological Spaces

4.Connectedness

5.Compactness

His proofs of many of the theorems are easily understood and
the problems he gives should not be to hard to do.

Chapter 4 has a section on homotopic paths.Homeomorphism is mentioned in Chapter 3.

This is a basic text in Topology.

Comment: Please, no links to illegal copies.

Comment: That is a illegal? I didn’t know. I will put the Amazon one Can I be upvoted.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths I had already replaced the link with the editor's site, but Amazon is acceptable as well.

Comment: Life plus 70 years.

Comment: Yep. And as far as I know, the author hasn't passed away yet.

Comment: Can I be upvoted for this post now

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain why you think it's a good book for self study, but yes, the answer is basically ok.

Comment: I annotated it with a new entry.What do you think?